# Why is the context provider state not shared between micro-frontends?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to split a monolithic React application into micro-frontends using Webpack Module Federation

The application relies on Context objects that are provided by the *Host* application. The context works as expected inside of the *Host* application, but not in the *Remote* application.

My code looks like this:

###### Host Application

Context and Context provider:

```js
// TestContext.js
import React from 'libs/react';

export const TestContext = React.createContext("Not Initialized :(");
```

```ts
// LocalSample.js
import React from 'libs/react';
import { TestContext } from './TestContext';

export default function () {
  const context = React.useContext(TestContext);
  return <div>Local: {context}</div>
}
```

```js
// App.js
import React, { Suspense } from 'libs/react';

import { TestContext } from './TestContext';

import RemoteSample from 'remote1/RemoteSample';
import LocalSample from './LocalSample';

export default function () {
  return (
    <TestContext.Provider value="Initialized :)">
      <LocalSample />
      <Suspense fallback={'loading...'}>
        <RemoteSample />
      </Suspense>
    </TestContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

###### Remote Application

```js
// RemoteSample.js
import React from 'libs/react';
import { TestContext } from 'host/TestContext';

export default function () {
  const context = React.useContext(TestContext);
  return <div>Remote: {context}</div>
}
```

Sample code is also available at https://github.com/christianheld/module-federation-context-repro

The output of the application is:

> Local: Initialized :)
> Remote: Not Initialized :(

How can I share the context value from *Host* to the *Remote* application?

Comment: I found a workaround here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LNcpralkjM&t=540 I will add it as answer

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to put your contexts in into the `shared` object in the Module Federation configuration.

In my application this looks like:

```js
shared: {
    "./src/MyContext": {}
}
```

I found the workaround in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LNcpralkjM&t=540

Please watch the video for the explanation.

Comment: Above implementation gives this error: 

ERROR in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename src_store_context_HostContext_HostContext_tsx.js

Comment: A full example for this implementation would be really helpful...Please share if there is.

Comment: @Christian Held - Could you please share the relevant code/config related to sharing the Context (in Host and Child)

Comment: I have the same issue, maybe someone solve this? ERROR in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename

Comment: For anyone in the future, if you are using alias in webpack, you need to add that config in the shared, example:

shared: {
    "./src/contexts/MyContext": {
          import: "contexts/MyContext"
     }
}