# How to dynamically unlock modules in webpack in a way that works with module federation singletons

Tags: react-context, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

We have a monorepo with many packages. For (complicated) reasons, we must keep some versions of some modules version locked to ensure certain changes are not used in production. However, this means we need to manually change the dependencies in package.json to a floating version (such as x.x.x) and run yarn install so we can use the latest code from the monorepo in development environments. Then we have to remember to change it back or at least not commit the package.json change to the library. These manual steps in our workflow are... frustrating. :-)

What we'd like to do is tell webpack under certain conditions to ignore the version from package.json for some modules. We'd like webpack to load the latest source files instead of the versioned files installed in node_modules.

I have found several ways that do load the source files however, none of them seem to work with module federation when you have objects that must be a singleton. In all cases I have found so far, multiple copies of the singleton object are created and our React context info isn't passing to our hooks. :-(

I have tried using the NormalModuleReplacementPlugin with a function callback to update the resource.request. In one case I changed the resource to be the absolute path to the source file (staring with /)

In another case I tried changing the request to an alias that pointed to the source code.

I have tried using an alias to directly override the content in the node_modules folder.

What makes this tricky is I can't share the entire module. So I'm only sharing the specific objects from the module that must be singletons as mentioned here: [Why is the context provider state not shared between micro-frontends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74206519/why-is-the-context-provider-state-not-shared-between-micro-frontends)

As long as I do nothing to try to unlock the module version, the React context object works as expected. The minute I do anything to the request, I get multiple instances of the context object in the browser and data is no longer passing from the provider module to the consumer module. I cannot figure out how module federation figures out when it can make a singleton and when it cannot.

The only thing I haven't tried yet is some kind of loader that hooked into the file loading process. If a read for a specific module was detected, have the loader get the source file and return it instead of letting the request go through to node_modules.

Does anyone have other ideas?